# Getting HTML table values using XPath in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to get some values from a table using the XPath of this table but it only returns `[]` (empty):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://riopretrans.com.br/linhas.php?ln=106"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.xpath("html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/center/font/table").each do |lines|
    puts lines.content
end
```

I found the table's XPath using Firebug so I think it's correct.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Remove `tbody/` from your XPath.

The `tbody` tag is part of the HTML spec for `table` tags, but it's rarely actually implemented in the HTML. Some browsers insert it, though it's not in the HTML for the page. Firebug then sees it, which you see, and think it must be so.

Even using "view source" can confuse you, because you expect that to be accurate, but the browser has already munged the content to include "tbody", so, well, basically they're lying to you.

You can confirm this by looking at the HTML that Nokogiri is getting. Use `puts doc.to_html['tbody']` and see if you get `"tbody"` or `nil`.

---

> ...Because in html file all of them were specified(written by programmer)

If you are positive they actually belong there, because they exist in the HTML source, then you'll need to take apart your XPath. Start with a broad path, and slowly add to it to narrow down your search.

The server is unreachable for me right now, so I can't confirm that, or dig into what the hierarchy should be, and show an example. (That's why actually giving us REAL HTML in your question is SO much better than a link which might not work.)

An alternate is to use XPath's `//` (search anywhere) with a less restrictive path, or CSS selectors. Either way, actually examine the HTML, instead of relying on Firebug's XPath, and determine what "landmarks" you can use in the source to navigate to your desired table. Today's HTML is chock-full of `id` and `class` parameters, or a particular series of tags that act as a finger-print for the table you want. Search for the minimum needed to pin-point that table.

If the table is something like `<table id="foo">`, then use `doc.at('table#foo')`. If it's in a `<div class="bar"><table>` use `doc.at('div.bar table')`. In any case, use the smallest sized accessor necessary to get the job done. That will increase your chances of success if anything in the HTML changes in the future.

Comment: All of them? Because in html file all of them were specified(written by programmer).

Comment: your `table#foo` and `'div.bar table'` is interesting.  Can you give me a source where I can see such short hand lots?

Comment: Those are standard CSS accessors. Nokogiri supports both XPath and CSS accessors that are jQuery compatible. I favor CSS because it is usually more readable; I think XPath is capable of doing more but it's also harder to read in my opinion, so I bounce back and forth depending on what I need.